# why cannot find Ws2_32.lib after installing VSTS 2010 SP1

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

why cannot find Ws2_32.lib after installing VSTS 2010 SP1?

Do I have to install windows SDK?

Comment: Did you add the lib to the linker section?

Comment: yes, I add to the linker section, but still has error.

Comment: I checked my VC folder, there is no ws2_32.lib.

Comment: Find out what happened to the Windows SDK that gets installed as well.  It should be present in c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\lib

Comment: @AdamLee sorry got called away - looks like people have answered now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, download and install the Windows SDK. It'll be the Windows 7 SDK in your case for VS2010.

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/98804-cannot-find-ws2_32-lib-socket-programming.html